# Print through network printer from android device

Tags: android

I developed an application that require to print document.Is it possible to print through network printer from android phone.(This printer connected to the network but not connected with WIFI.)

Is it require printer driver to print through network printer.

Comment: did you get any solution? because m also searching on that. @Shanto George